# JavaFX : Keep line bound to the center of two panes

Tags: javafx, binding, line

I'm new to JavaFX and I have troubles with bindings.
I'm coding a game in which I draw lines between panes contains in the cells of a `GridPane`. I can draw lines with the code below, but I'd like to have the line coordinates to scale as the pane gets bigger when I resize the window.

The `Pane`s and the `GridPane` already resize as wanted, and I've managed to bind the line's width to the size of the scene (cellSize is a binding on the scene width/height).

```
Pane lastPane = panes[lastC][lastR];
Pane curPane = panes[c][r];

Bounds boundsInSceneLast = lastPane.localToScene(lastPane.getBoundsInLocal());
Bounds boundsInSceneCur = curPane.localToScene(curPane.getBoundsInLocal());
double lastX = (boundsInSceneLast.getMinX() + boundsInSceneLast.getMaxX())/2;
double lastY = (boundsInSceneLast.getMinY() + boundsInSceneLast.getMaxY())/2;
double x = (boundsInSceneCur.getMinX() + boundsInSceneCur.getMaxX())/2;
double y= (boundsInSceneCur.getMinY() + boundsInSceneCur.getMaxY())/2;

Line line = new Line(lastX, lastY, x, y);

line.setStroke(Color.web(couleurs.get(symbole)));
line.strokeWidthProperty().bind(cellSize.divide(10));
line.setStrokeLineCap(StrokeLineCap.BUTT);

anchor.getChildren().add(line);
lines.get(symbole).add(line);
```

`anchor` is an `AnchorPane` which is the root of my `Scene` and `lines` is a `HashMap` which keeps track of the lines, but those shouldn't be relevant to my problem.

I'm sure it can be done pretty simply but I've searched the web pretty deeply and all I could understand and try wasn't getting the job done so I'm asking for your help.

Thanks in advance !! :)

Comment: Is the `AnchorPane` the parent of both the `GridPane` and all the `Line`s? Would adding the `Line`s to the `GridPane` be an option, as long as this does not interfer with the layout of the other nodes?

Comment: Yes the AnchorPane is the parent of both the GridPane and all the Lines. In fact the AnchorPane is the parent of a StackPane and all the lines, and this StackPane contains the GridPane and a label centered compared to the GridPane.

Well I wouldn't be against it but what would it change to my problem ? And will I be able to draw lines over several cells of the grid this way ? :o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's problematic to listen to the bounds of a `Node` in the scene since there is no property for the scene bounds and every `Parent` on the path to the root node of the scene could apply a transform that require you to adjust the position of the line ends. This would require you to add a listener to descendant of the `Pane`s.

It would be simpler to make the lines a part of the `GridPane` itself as unmanaged nodes. This allows you to work with the bounds of the nodes in the `GridPane`:

```
final Pane lastPane = panes[lastC][lastR];
final Pane curPane = panes[c][r];

final Line line = new Line();

line.setStroke(Color.web(couleurs.get(symbole)));
line.strokeWidthProperty().bind(cellSize.divide(10));
line.setStrokeLineCap(StrokeLineCap.BUTT);

InvalidationListener listener = o -> {
    Bounds boundsInSceneLast = lastPane.getBoundsInParent();
    Bounds boundsInSceneCur = curPane.getBoundsInParent();
    double lastX = (boundsInSceneLast.getMinX() + boundsInSceneLast.getMaxX())/2;
    double lastY = (boundsInSceneLast.getMinY() + boundsInSceneLast.getMaxY())/2;
    double x = (boundsInSceneCur.getMinX() + boundsInSceneCur.getMaxX())/2;
    double y = (boundsInSceneCur.getMinY() + boundsInSceneCur.getMaxY())/2;

    line.setStartX(lastX);
    line.setStartY(lastY);
    line.setEndX(x);
    line.setEndY(y);
};

// listen to location & size changes of panes in the GridPane
lastPane.boundsInParentProperty().addListener(listener);
curPane.boundsInParentProperty().addListener(listener);

// initial refresh
listener.invalidated(null);

// add line to GridPane without considering it for layout
line.setManaged(false);
gridPane.getChildren().add(line);

lines.get(symbole).add(line);
```